# How to split a row in multiple rows SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a row in sql table to multiple rows in other table.
example: say if i'm having a table 'UserDetail' and he has 2 address's (home, office...) then the table looks like...

[image]

I wand the result to be in the second table as shown in the image

Comment: yes i did... but couldn't find a solution in one select query

Comment: Well share the code you wrote after you did research and attempted to solve the problem

Comment: You should consider normalizing this structure.   What happens if a person has 3 addresses for example?     If you normalize the address to a separate table, you'll find the queries easier to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can CROSS JOIN or CROSS APPLY the table to a list of numbers.
Then use IIF or CASE to get the correspondent numbered fields.

Or CROSS APPLY on the address values directly on the table.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @UserTable table (UserId int, Address1Line varchar(30), Address1City varchar(30), Address1State varchar(30), Address2Line varchar(30), Address2City varchar(30), Address2State varchar(30));

insert into @UserTable (UserId, Address1Line, Address1City, Address1State, Address2Line, Address2City, Address2State) values 
(1,'Wonder Lane 42','WonderTown', 'WonderState', 'Somewhere 1 B', 'Nowhere', 'Anywhere'),
(2,'Backstreet 69','Los Libros', 'Everland', 'Immortal Cave 777', 'Ghost City', 'The Wild Lands');

-- Cross Join on numbers
select UserId, 
case n when 1 then Address1Line when 2 then Address2Line end as [Address],
case n when 1 then Address1City when 2 then Address2City end as [City],
case n when 1 then Address1State when 2 then Address2State end as [State]
from @UserTable u
cross join (values (1),(2)) as nums(n);

-- Cross Apply on Adress values
select UserId, [Address], [City], [State]
from @UserTable Usr
cross apply (values 
 (1, Address1Line, Address1City, Address1State),
 (2, Address2Line, Address2City, Address2State)
) AS Addr(n, [Address], [City], [State]);
```

**Both return:**

```
UserId Address           City       State
------ ----------------- ---------- --------------
1      Wonder Lane 42    WonderTown WonderState
1      Somewhere 1 B     Nowhere    Anywhere
2      Backstreet 69     Los Libros Everland
2      Immortal Cave 777 Ghost City The Wild Lands
```

Comment: @Niks FYI, I've included a second method that also has a number of which address is shown.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "union all" to do that like:

```
select * into newTable
from
(
select UserId, Address1Line as Address, Address1City as City, Address1State as State
from myTable
union all
select UserId, Address2Line as Address, Address2City as City, Address2State as State
from myTable
) tmp
```

If you use just UNION instead of UNION ALL you would also be removing the duplicates where Address1 and Address2 is same.

Comment: You don't need aliases in the second half of the union, and in fact they will be ignored.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my laziness (copy & paste).

Comment: Its a good idea, but need a different approach to do this, don't want to do this using a temp table or union.

Comment: @Niks, Where is the temp table? And why would you want to avoid UNION?

Comment: @TorstenGrust, right. I don't have any idea why one would want to avoid a keyword.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I assume it's probably because his real query is more complicated than what the simplification of the question makes it look like.  If one has to join other tables and use criteria on them then those could be added in the outer query. But then the subquery would still union all records from myTable, while perhaps only a few are needed. And adding the joins and criteria inside the subquery for each unioned select wouldn't look nice.  Anyway, sql server requires that subqueries also have an alias.  I know, it's a silly thing to fix in your query.

Comment: @LukStorms, added the alias thanks:) I don't think a more complicated query would make a difference, that could be added as a CTE at top.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Cross Apply

```
;WITH CTE(UseriD,Address1Line,Address1City,Address1State,Address2Line,Address2City,Address2State )
AS
(
SELECT 1,'Line1','City1','State1','Line2','City2','State2'
)
SELECT UseriD,[Address],City,[State]
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (Address1Line,Address1City,Address1State ),
                     (Address2Line,Address2City,Address2State )
            )AS Dt([Address],City,[State])
```

Result

```
UseriD  Address City    State
-----------------------------
1       Line1   City1   State1
1       Line2   City2   State2
```

Demo:http://rextester.com/KHFUM28227